# Fail2ban Jail List

Tags: apache-httpd, dns, fail2ban

Recently our website starting loading extremely slow when browsing publicly to FDQN. Using IP of the website it will load the main file, but not dependencies. Curl show the TCP exchange happen in a normal amount of time. I'm basically troubleshooting blindly so I had our developer look into it and he showed me the Fail2ban jail list. attached is a screenshot.

My question is if the Jail list supposed to have apache, apache-nhome, wordpress, etc.. listed?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) Copy/paste the text into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a 3rd party plugin for weather data that was having problems. We removed the plugin and site loads fine now.